# lgcrypt not found while compiling libvirt

Tags: opensuse, libvirt

I am compiling libvirt. while compiling I got to install a lot of libraries which were appeared as dependencies. but I am not able to resolve the following error:

linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcrypt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I have libgcrypt already installed in my system:

~/libvirt> sudo zypper install libgcrypt11
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'libgcrypt11' is already installed.
No update candidate for 'libgcrypt11-1.5.0-2.1.2.i586'. The highest available version is already installed.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.

Please help me if I am missing some packages?

Comment: I have libgcrypt11-devel also installed in my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had figured it out. There were no pacakges missing but some how my /bin was not reading teh libgcrypt. after uninstalling the and reinstalling libgcrypt I got it working.